# What makes a movie a "cult classic"?

Tags: genre

As the title says, what actually defines a **cult classic** film? As an example, the Cube series ([Cube](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0123755/), [Cube 2 Hypbercube](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0285492/), and [Cube Zero](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0377713/)) are labeled as Cult Classics, but it does not seem like it is about a cult in any manner

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult_film , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cult_following , and http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CultClassic .

Comment: *Cube 2-4* cult classics? Ridiculous! (From this highly subjective comment you might see that there is probably a large degree of subjectivity involved in the actual definition of *"Cult Classic"*, it doesn't have anything to do with the plot involving a cult, though.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A cult film has cult following, and a film will be said to have a cult following when it has a small but very passionate fan base. eg.- [Fight Club](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fight_Club), [Memento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_%28film%29), [Rounders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounders_%28film%29) etc.
These movies were not commercial success, but their fan base is very passionate about them.
 Though it is not necessary for a cult movie to receive critical and commercial acclaim, sometimes a cult movie achieves it eg. - [Pulp Fiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulp_Fiction), the 1975 indian movie [Sholay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sholay) etc. These movies not only have a cult folllowing they also had commercial and critical success. This when a cult movie becomes a

> Cult Classic

Comment: So basically, if it has a *dedicated* group of fans, it is a cult following, even if it also has *lots* of fans?

Comment: Thanks for reminding me of *Rounders*, seen it a long time ago and really enjoyed it (didn't know it's regarded a cult film, though). And nice answer by the way.

Comment: @Luke precisely

Comment: @ChristianRau yeah Rounders is a cult film. I read it on wikipedia and BTW it's one of my all time favorites :)